# NoMethodError: undefined method `eager_load_paths' for #<I18n::Config:0x00007fceade8c0f0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eager-loading, ruby-on-rails-6, zeitwerk

In my rails 6 app running ruby 2.7, I am trying to eager load all the files using Zeitwerk. Here is a snippet of my application.rb file:

```
class Application < Rails::Application
config.load_defaults "6.0"
Zeitwerk::Loader.eager_load_all

# Application configuration can go into files in config/initializers
# -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded after loading
# the framework and any gems in your application.

# Middlewares
config.middleware.insert 0, Rack::UTF8Sanitizer
config.middleware.use Rack::Attack
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/*"]
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/models/**/*"]
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/observers/*"]
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/middleware/*"]
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/validators/**/*"]
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/**/concerns/*"]
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/operations/**/*"]
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/scrubbers/**/*"]
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/workers/**/*"]
config.paths.add "#{config.root}/app/operations/", eager_load: true

# Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
# Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
config.time_zone = "UTC"

# The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}')].reject { |f| File.fnmatch("#{Rails.root.to_s}/config/locales/**/x_*.yml", f) }
config.i18n.available_locales = [:"en", :"fr", :"fr_en"]
config.i18n.default_locale = :en

# Precompile additional assets.
# application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
config.assets.precompile += ["public.css", "public.js", "public_payments.js", "email.css", "pdf.css", "pronotif.css"]

config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
  end
end
```

end

However, when I run this I get this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `eager_load_paths' for #<I18n::Config:0x00007fceade8c0f0>
```

Any solution for this will be helpful

Comment: Hold your horses. There is no reason you have to add all those directories to the autoload paths. Rails will already by default add every subdirectory of `/app` to the autoload paths. Adding `Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/*"]` is also kind of an ant-pattern as it will add every subdirectory of  `lib` as roots. I also don't get why you think you want to autoload everything in `application.rb` as that will just ruin code reloading in dev/test. This smells very much like an X&Y question - whats the actual problem that your trying to solve with all this?

Answer (score 2):

### Problem

Aside from the fact that your application.rb is not in a good shape (as @max mentioned in the [first comment to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60649082/nomethoderror-undefined-method-eager-load-paths-for-i18nconfig0x00007fce#comment107311820_60649082)) the problem [is known](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/37966) and [already fixed](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/da28edf9baf0bd83b5308564bdcd8f4673b492bd) for Rails.

Unfortunately (as time of writing, with Rails 6.0.2.2) the fix is *currently not public*.

### Temporary Workaround

But **until then** you might copy the [patched rake task](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/da28edf9baf0bd83b5308564bdcd8f4673b492bd/railties/lib/rails/tasks/zeitwerk.rake) to your app under a file named `lib/tasks/local_zeitwerk.rake` and change line 41 to:

```rb
namespace :local_zeitwerk do
```

and then execute the check task with

```
bin/rails local_zeitwerk:check
```